# jQuery scroll page offset not working

Tags: jquery

I've seen this question posted many times, but either the example is broken or I can't get it to work.

I have a sticky nav bar which is fixed to the top of the page. There is an anchor link that scrolls the page to that location. It works but when it needs to be offset by the height of the sticky nav.

I have set a height in px and also tried to get the height in a variable.
Console tells me it's getting the correct height. But it's not calculating it or doing anything with it. Or maybe it and has not been implemented properly.

If anyone can shed some light, that would be ace!

Here is the JSFiddle:

```js
var $root = $('html, body');
var offset = $('#sticky-header').outerHeight();
$('a.anchor').click(function() {
  $root.animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).position().top - offset
  }, 500);
  return false;
});
```

```css
#sticky-header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}

#bigdiv {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: white;
}

#bigdiv2 {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: purple;
}

#reservations {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sticky-header" style="position: fixed; top: 0px;">
  <p>
    some textxt
    <a href="#anchor">ANCHOR BUTTON</a>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="bigdiv"></div>

<div id="anchor">
  reservation text
</div>

<div id="bigdiv2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector a.anchor in the click function was wrong. I made some changes to your code, take a look now it works properly:

```js
var $root = $('html, body');
var offset = $('#sticky-header').outerHeight();
$('#hrefScroll').click(function() {
     var targetName = $(this).attr("href")
     var targetOffset = $(targetName).offset().top-offset
     $root.animate({
                scrollTop: targetOffset
      }, 1000)
        return false;
});
```

```css
#sticky-header {

  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
#bigdiv {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: white;
}
#bigdiv2 {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: purple;
}
#reservations {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sticky-header" style="position: fixed; top: 0px;">
<p>
some textxt
<a href="#anchor" id="hrefScroll">ANCHOR BUTTON</a>
</p>
</div>

<div id="bigdiv"></div>

<div id="anchor">
  reservation text
</div>

<div id="bigdiv2"></div>
```

Comment: Yay, Thank you!!

Comment: It actually doesn't work on my site. The height of the div is dynamic. The size is added to a style tag in the div. even though console can see it, it might be the problem...

Comment: You can get easily the pixels with next: $("#yourDiv").height() in each click

Comment: Or with this: parseInt($('#yourDiv').css('height'), 10);

Comment: Didn't I have that in the var = offset? Where would I implement your second option?

Comment: All your codes work, I think it's being overwritten. The site used z-indexes, though the value is the value. I've removed code concerning that div, still doesn't like it...